# Can use Next.js to replace React-Router totally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, next.js

Previously, I am using React + React-Router, I think the react-router is kind of complicated, I think Next.js's router is more straightforward, so my question is: can Next.js replace react-router totally? I am not familiar with Next.js, is there anyone can give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

NextJS creates routes with the information from your local pages directory. While this is much simpler than the other configurations, there are two disadvantages for this approach:

1. It cannot create dynamic routes
2. It cannot create nested routes

NextJS prefers a [custom Node server](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls) to get past these disadvantages. If you would like a shortcut, [Next Routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) could help.

While you could certainly use React Router on the client side, it will not support SSR, so server side navigation is a big No. You would also have to move to HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter. You can find the issue [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1632). It would certainly be better to use NextJS router for supporting functionalities like dynamic imports and prefetching.

Comment: "If you would like a shortcut" makes Next Routes sound like a compromise. Are there downsides when compared to a custom server with next.js or Gatsby?